# How to apply auto shrinking to UIButton title?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel

Imagine the following example:

There is a button like this

[image]

The text is set programmatically since it is timer dependent. I want the title font size adjust to the bounds of the button. For typical UILabel, after constraints are set, it is easy to apply auto-shrinking. Is there any way to do it to the title as it is possible for normal UILabel?

I tried

```
self.alertButton.titleLabel?.sizeToFit()
```

but it does nothing. Also in interface builder I cannot see such option as it is in case of typical UILabel.

Thanks

Comment: What on earth does "make this text responsive along with the button" even _mean_? It is completely unclear what you want to do.

Comment: Is it better right now? Could you try to answer the question instead of downvoting?

Comment: No, why is it better? What does "apply auto shrinking to the title" mean? I see nothing wrong with the button, and you have not explained what you think is wrong with it.

Comment: Sir, I strongly appreciate your experience and knowledge, but this is not kind that you penalize me for every word I wrote.

Comment: @DCDC, If you never received negative feedback, how would you know what is bad?

Comment: Guys, so give me this feedback, what is the best sentence to describe my problem? I'm really willing to know, but for now I only hear "what does that even mean?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question isn't overly clear but I'm guessing you want the button's label to automatically use a smaller font if the length of the label is too long for the button. Is this correct?

Assuming so, simply do:

```
self.alertButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
```

Comment: works for me, thank you! however, I think now it has some problem with position, it seems to be a little bit lower than it was

Comment: Look into the `UILabel baselineAdjustment` property.

Comment: Thanks, now it's fine. Happy to have people like you on SO board!:)